# Rails 4 Dynamic Form Fields and Form Object

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nested-forms

I have a reasonably complicated set of models and associations and I want users of my application to be able to enter information for all of them in a single form. This seems like a job for form objects. So I did that and it works fine. But I'm struggling to understand how I would add form fields dynamically. So if a Professor object `has_many` Papers how would I add fields to the form since a form object doesn't have things like `accepts_nested_parameters_for`?

I made a minimal working example that you can see. The example works for adding three models that are related to each other. However, I don't know how to dynamically add form fields and associate them with new instances of some of the models. https://github.com/blackfist/formobj. I'll put the form object and the controller here but if you need more context, check out the repo.

There are a lot of tutorials out there on pieces of this, but I can't find a unifying source. For example, tutorials on form objects but not dynamically added fields. Or examples on dynamically adding fields when you've got a`ccepts_nested_parameters_for`. Also, I see a lot of things that point to link_to_function which I understand to be deprecated in Rails 4. So I would prefer not to use that as a solution here.

Here is the form object

```
class ProfessorForm
  include ActiveModel::Model

  attr_accessor :prof_name, :prof_subject,
    :uni_name, :uni_state, :uni_city, :paper_title, :paper_date,
    :paper_publication

  validates :prof_name, presence: true
  validates :uni_name, presence: true
  validates :paper_title, presence:true

  def save
    if valid?
      persist!
      true
    else
      false
    end
  end

  def model_name
    Professor.model_name
  end

  private
    def persist!
      @uni = University.create!(name: uni_name, city:uni_city, state: uni_state)
      @pro = @uni.professors.create!(name: prof_name, subject: prof_subject)
      @pap = @pro.papers.create!(title: paper_title, date:paper_date, publication: paper_publication)
    end

end
```

and the Professor controller

```
class ProfessorsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @professors = Professor.all
  end

  def new
    @professor_form = ProfessorForm.new
  end

  def create
    @professor_form = ProfessorForm.new(professor_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @professor_form.save
        format.html {redirect_to professors_url, notice: 'Professor created successfully.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end

  end

  private
    def professor_params
      params.require(:professor).permit(:prof_name, :prof_subject,
        :uni_name, :uni_city, :uni_state, :paper_title, :paper_date,
        :paper_publication)
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

For dynamically adding or deleting fields for related models, you can try [gem 'nested_forms'](https://github.com/ryanb/nested_form) by Ryan Bates. It allows you to add multiple records in a single form submission. I don't think a form object can solve your problem.

Basically after install you can put the following code into your view:

```
<%= f.fields_for :papers do |paper_form| %>
  <%= paper_form.text_field :name %>
  <%= paper_form.link_to_remove "Remove this paper" %>
<% end %>
<p><%= f.link_to_add "Add a paper", :papers %></p>
```

The `link_to_add` and `link_to_remove` create or remove the fields, and dynamically create multiple records in submission.

Also, I'm not sure if your form object requires `attr_reader :model_name` to work.

Comment: The form object doesn't have a `has_many` relationship with anything so I don't believe I can use f.fields_for. But I used the form object because the alternative doesn't seem to work either.

It doesn't work well to have `accepts_nested_attributes_for` an objects parent. In this case I would have to have a Professor `belongs_to` University and `accepts_nested_attributes_for` the University. Unless I did it wrong, that doesn't appear to work.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that the question was asked a long time ago, but still try to answer it, suddenly it could be helpful for someone.
I suggest to use [virtus](https://github.com/solnic/virtus) gem. It allows you to define attributes on form classes. So, you can create Paper class:

```
class Paper
  include Virtus.model

  attribute :title, String
  attribute :date, Date
  attribute :publication, String
end
```

And include it inside your form class. So, your `ProfessorForm` will look like this:

```
class ProfessorForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  include Virtus.model

  attribute :name
  attribute :subject
  attribute :papers, Array[Paper]

  ...
end
```

`professor_params` in controller will be defined this way:

```
def professor_params
  params.require(ProfessorForm.new).permit(...)
end
```

And change `create` method to iterate papers array and create them:

```
def create
  @professor_form = ProfessorForm.new(professor_params)
  respond_to do |format|
    if @professor_form.valid?
      professor = Professor.create!(name: professor_params[:name], subject: professor_params[:subject])
      professor_params[:papers].each do |professor_paper|
        professor.papers.create!(title: professor_paper[:title], date: professor_paper[:date], publication: professor_paper[:publication])
    else
      format.html { render :new }
    end
  end
end
```

I didn't mention about `University` and its association with `Professor` but it could be done the same way.